# How do you not just drop the rock?

Tags: assassins-creed-valhalla

When I do the cairns, I have a hard time because I can't figure out how to not just drop the rock from a height and destroy my tower.

Every solution I see online seem to be able to move down the rock and place it softly on top of the pile instead of dropping it from a foot up.

But on PS5, I can't seem to figure out what is the control to move the rock up and down.
So what is the control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control scheme overlay that activates when interacting with a cairns challenge (see below) fails to indicate that you can raise and lower a stone simply by respectively pushing up and pulling down on the left analogue stick (without holding the square button) - if I remember correctly.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I figured it out and now feels stupid. I tought up/down was going further/closer to you, but it did go down. Its just the camera angle that made it seem like it stayed same height.

Comment: I understand the same thing happened to me, and I suspect many other players.